# react-jsonschema-form-extra asynctypeahead, set initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

How can I set initial value from db in react-jsonschema-form-extra asynctypeahead?
I can save ID of element selected in db, but when I come back to the form with loaded values typeahead fields are empty.

This is my code:

```
  user: {
    "ui:field": "asyncTypeahead",
    asyncTypeahead: {
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      minLength: 1,
      //selected: {'username':'Bret'},
      selected: {'name':'Leanne Graham'},
      mapping: 'id',
      selectHintOnEnter: true,
      //labelKey: "username",
      labelKey: (option) => `${option.name} ${option.username}`,
      //overrideOptions: true
    }
  }
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you please post your React code?

Comment: Here complete code:
[code on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-jsonschema-form-extra-asynctypeahead-k47bh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Anyway, we think the way is to prefetch data in options.